# Automatic chatroomDidLeave after chatDidFail. Why? Oh why? [Quickblox]

Tags: quickblox

Every time we try to reconnect after a chatDidFail event, we:

1. login in chat
2. enter room
3. automatically get kicked out of the the room (chatRoomDidLeave event)
4. when we try to re-join the room, we get kicked out again (chatRoomDidLeave)
5. and it loops

why, oh why?
Why does Quickblox kicks us out of any room after we try to reconnect following a chatDidFail event?

All we do is:

```
-(void)chatDidFailWithError:(int)code
{
    [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];
}


- (void)chatRoomDidLeave:(NSString *)roomName
{
   [[QBChat instance] createOrJoinRoomWithName:@"roomName" membersOnly:NO persistent:YES];
}
```

We're running out of ideas on this one...

Comment: Are your code <createOrJoinRoomWithName:@"roomName"> or <createOrJoinRoomWithName:roomName> ?

Comment: It is:
<createOrJoinRoomWithName:@"roomName">

Comment: Are you implement delegate method chatRoomDidNotEnter:error: ? Are this method fire and if yes which error it contain?

Comment: chatRoomDidNotEnter is implemented and is not fired up.

Comment: hm, I don't have any ideas. Maybe you have wrong logic in your code. Or maybe something else. What you have in chatDidLogin method?  
Are you also invoke -createOrJoinRoomWithName: in it?

Comment: Quickblox support helped us out:
- we were going to background without leaving the room;
- when we came back, if chatDidFail, it would reconnect to chat, enter the room and automatically leave the room;
- we need to leave the room and on chatRoomDidLeave do "currentRoom = nil" so next time we reconnect and enter the room, quickblox chat server won't kick us out.

Comment: Mario: I didn't understand the solution - what does "we need to leave room and on chatRoomDidLeave do 'currentRoom = nil'" mean? Where do you set the "currentRoom = nil"?

Comment: Put "currentRoom = nil" inside chatRoomDidLeave.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this. It seems that Quickblox chat implementation isn't able to recover on it's own, when the application goes background and you don't leave the chat room.

This can be solved by having the ChatManager (your own singleton class used to manage chat connections) to store the currently shown room (self.currentRoom) and automatically leave the room, and log out when application resigns active. And when the application will enter foreground, you log in and rejoin the room.

Add these to the singleton class `(id)init`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleApplicationWillResignActiveNotification:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleApplicationEnterForegroundNotification:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

And the property implementation for the current room:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) QBChatRoom *currentRoom;
```

And then implement the corresponding handlers (you can also invalidate the presence timer here):

```
- (void)handleApplicationWillResignActiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    lg(@"Application resigning active");
    if (self.currentRoom) {
        if (self.presenceTimer) {
            [self.presenceTimer invalidate];
            self.presenceTimer = nil;
        }
        [self leaveRoom:self.currentRoom clearRoom:NO];
        [[QBChat instance] logout];
    }
}

- (void)handleApplicationEnterForegroundNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    lg(@"Application entering foreground.");
    if (![[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:self.currentUser]) {
        lg(@"Logging in failed for some reason.");
    }
}
```

Then in `chatDidLogin` you do the following:

```
- (void)chatDidLogin
{
    ...

    if (self.currentRoom) {
        lg(@"Auto-joining current room.");
        [self joinRoom:self.currentRoom completionBlock:nil];
    }

    ...
}
```

Store the room reference when you enter a room:

```
- (void)chatRoomDidEnter:(QBChatRoom *)room
{
    ...    
    self.currentRoom = room;
    ...    
}
```

Make sure that you don't clear `self.currentRoom` when you leave the room on `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`, so that there's a reference for the current room when the application comes foreground.